# How to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x+\cos x}{e^x-\sin x}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x+\cos x}{e^x-\sin x}$$

Can someone help me find the limit without using the L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: This could help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108692/limit-of-lim-x-to-infty-fracex-cos-xex-sin-3x

Comment: Is it the limit when $x$ tends to $+$ or $-\infty$?

Comment: As x gets to be large $e^x$ will be very large while $\sin x, \cos x,$ both be bounded by $-1,1,$ will be trivial.  If you want to be slightly more rigorous, multiply numerator and denominator by $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x+\cos x}{e^x-\sin 3x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108692/limit-of-lim-x-to-infty-fracex-cos-xex-sin-3x)

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^x + \cos x}{e^x - \sin x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1 + e^{-x} \cos x}{1 - e^{-x}\sin x} = \dfrac{\lim_{x \to \infty}(1 + e^{-x} \cos x)}{\lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - e^{-x} \sin x)} = \dfrac{1}{1} = 1. \tag 1$

Comment: Congratulations, you now have 40000 reputation!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  thank you sir, you will always be remembered as the one who put me there!  Cheers!

Comment: @stuartstevenson Note *without* in "**without** using the L'Hospital's rule" :-).

Comment: @stuartstevenson:  I believe if you read the question carefully you will agree it says "*without* using the L'Hopital's . . .".

Comment: @stuartstevenson:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Answer (score 1):

When you substitute $\infty$ in $e^x$ It becomes $\infty$ which is not desirable .

But we know that $\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}$ is equal to 0 .

So we divide $N^r$ And $D^r$ By $e^x$.

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1+\cos x\cdot e^{-x}}{1- \sin x \cdot e^{-x}} 
$$

Now ,

$$
lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x} = \frac{-1<a\ number<1}{e^\infty}=0
$$

Similarly
$$
lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin x}{e^x} = \frac{-1<a\ number<1}{e^\infty}=0
$$

So your answer becomes

$$
lim_ {x\to\infty} \frac{1+0}{1-0}= 1
$$

And that's the final answer .

;-)

Answer (score 1):

An option :

Let $x >0:$

$f(x)=\dfrac{e^x+\cos x}{e^x-\sin x}$.

$\dfrac{e^x-1}{e^x+1} \lt f(x) \lt \dfrac{e^x +1}{e^x-1}$.

$1- 2\dfrac{1}{e^x+1} \lt f(x) \lt 1+ 2\dfrac{1}{e^x-1}$

Take the limit $x \rightarrow \infty. $